# Should we also close "Are the Mars landings real?" questions as duplicates of "Are the Moon landings real"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In [this answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1731/12102) to *Do we need a canonical Mars Landings Are Real answer?* I propose that the work and consensus that went into the closing of Moon landing hoaxer class questions as *duplicates* of our now established canonical question [How do we know the Apollo Moon landings are real?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28172/12102) with several excellent answers should not be duplicated again for Mars, and again for each new solar system body.

Instead, I argue that since the nature of this class of questions is to play games with the Stack Exchange site, to troll, and to use question posts to push theories rather than to ask question, the specific solar system body doesn't matter.

I said we should close all of these as duplicates of the canonical Moon question, not just the Moon ones.

An additional benefit of closing them all as dupes of instead of a hodgepodge of generic close reasons is that we will have this activity quantified and catalogued in case that is of interest in the future.

That's my view. What do others think?

**Question::** Should we also close "Are the Mars landings real?" questions as duplicates of "Are the Moon landings real"?

Current example, I've voted to close as duplicate of our canonical: [Is this debris from the Space Crane from Perserverance?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50639/12102) which invites opinions and embeds a crank hoaxer video.

Comment: In 2019 [*How could we fake a moon landing now?*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/144269/how-could-we-fake-a-moon-landing-now) was asked on SE World Building. You might find some of the answers interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we should. Three of the five points in the main answer of [How do we know the Apollo Moon landings are real?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28172/58) are directly applicable. The fourth applies as well, though it's written to address evidence for the Moon specifically.

The questions are similar enough in spirit, and the main answer there is sufficient to address both.

---

That said, the specific one you wanted to close as a duplicate in this case--I'm not sure if it fits well within the "Are the Mars landings real?" framework. It seems the conspiracy being spread here is not that we haven't landed probes on Mars, but that something there is being covered up. I have no issue with us closing these questions as well, but they don't really work well as duplicates of the Moon landing question because that just addresses whether the landing is real, not whether something else happened during the landing that was covered up.

Comment: Reading the comments on that video made me weep for humanity.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Truly :(

Answer (score 1):

There has been a recent cluster of questions insinuating that Chinese/CNSA landings on Mars are fake.

I want to make it clear that such questions are just as bad as those that allege that U.S./NASA efforts are not real.  Conspiracy theories should not be tolerated here, regardless of which country is being accused.

Comment: Is there any evidence of such "toleration" here?