# Do "calculate satellite orbits" questions need a canonical community wiki like Astronomy SE's "...find positions of the planets...and visualize them?"

Tags: discussion, answers

I just wrote [this answer to *Orbit prediction for satellites using Kepler model*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/63704/12102) which is a variation on an oft-asked question category about calculating orbits for artificial satellites (Earth-bound or deep space). I've answered many, but *for perhaps the first time* I didn't go back and find all the answers I usually link to that explain how to do this various ways using various techniques and approximations, from getting $t(\theta)$ analytically in a Kepler orbit to including oblateness and General relativity into numerical orbit integration.

I guess I'm running out of steam on that topic and probably won't be writing those kinds of answers in the future, unless there's a cool "niche" aspect to the question.

I wonder if some kind of canonical question and community wiki answer similar to Astronomy SE's incredibly useful [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982) would work here as well.

That way all the goodies would either be in one place, or probably better yet, be *linked to from one place*.

It could be limited to satellites in Earth orbit, or spacecraft trajectories in general (deep space, Lagrange-point-associated orbits) **as long as the question was specifically a "How to calculate..." via computer.**

1. Does this sound useful?
2. If so, what would it look like?
3. Since there are also some good, instructive answers in Astronomy SE that nicely complement those here, would it be okay to include links to them as well?
4. OR should we NOT reference this body of work, and let new folks write new answers to new questions, then close them as duplicates later?<sup>1</sup>

---

*Just for some examples* of the types of answers I won't be (re-)writing in the future, see:

- [user:12102 is:answer kepler [orbital-mechanics]](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+is%3Aanswer+kepler+%5Borbital-mechanics%5D)
- [user:12102 is:answer numerical [orbital-mechanics]](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+is%3Aanswer+numerical+%5Borbital-mechanics%5D)
- [user:12102 is:answer solve_ivp [orbital-mechanics]](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+is%3Aanswer+solve_ivp+%5Borbital-mechanics%5D)
- [user:12102 is:answer odeint [orbital-mechanics]](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+is%3Aanswer+odeint+%5Borbital-mechanics%5D)

<sup>1</sup>This is not my personal favorite option - I think SE sites should leverage existing material *and build on it* rather than ignore it or close (potentially insufficiently) answered questions as duplicates of older ones. [uhoh's lemmas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377004/303080) apply here, especially #1 and #3;

> Stack Exchange is a collaborative effort to generate good answers to on-topic questions.
>
> ...Asking of questions is a superposition of (at least) two things; seeking solutions to our immediate problem or query and the *facilitation of interesting, helpful and informative answers for the **benefit of future readers.***

which is why I feel that *linking* is so important, and centralizing those links could be so helpful.

Comment: imo you and several other users who have Been Around Long Enough are in a wonderful position to recognize This Has Been Asked Before and then to inform users who haven't Been Around Long Enough that "this here partially answers your question" or "this is a duplicate of this other thing."

Comment: @ErinAnne while https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impermanence applies to everything, my time remaining (and that of some of the "around long enough"s is probably shorter than the site's, so at least for me, I'd like to leave something for future readers when I'm gone. A great community wiki will help future question-closers and question-answerers.

Comment: Although..., where should we create a draft of the canonical post (if the idea is going to continue) (and is a draft needed?), should it be a community wiki or posted by one person?

Comment: @DialFrost after discussion in one (or two meta posts here, [How do we know the Apollo Moon landings are real?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28172/12102) was created in the main site is our *de facto* canonical answer to which we close all hoaxer and conspiracy theory-driving questions. But for this, it we could consider a meta Q&A like [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/12102)

Comment: @DialFrost (Those previous meta discussions were (in reverse chronological order): [How to determine when a question should or should not be duped to "...Moon landings are real?"](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1044/12102) and before that [The answer to the question about Moon landing hoax theories](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1023/12102) and before that [What shall our canonical question and answer regarding moon hoax conspiracy theories be?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1011/12102)) I think the process worked quite well.

Comment: Wait my bad I misunderstood what you meant, a meta Q&A to collect information is viable, but I think starting off with the main site should work slightly better??

Comment: @DialFrost I have to catch a bus (and haven't finished my required dose of coffee yet), I'll give it some more thought...

Comment: @DialFrost Only slightly related (in mera) [Do we need a canonical **Mars** Landings Are Real answer?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1730/12102) and [Should we also close "Are the Mars landings real?" questions as duplicates of "Are the Moon landings real"?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1737/12102) (spoiler alert: "yes")

Comment: Btw count me in if you need any help on this canonical post ;)

Comment: @DialFrost okay I'll ping you if I get any further idea what it might look like -  make sure to follow this question (click "follow" under it) so that if there's any activity of any kind you'll be notified.

Answer (score 4):

As a relatively new user with not so much experience of being on this site, my opinion might be of less value than other long-term users on this site. Nevertheless, I will provide my opinion on this issue.

> 1. This sounds useful?

Yes, I highly approve of canonical posts, especially since I have tried making and starting one in the English Language Learners (ELL) site.

> 2. If so, what would it look like?

There are many different aspects that an ideal canonical post should cover and include:

- be general - a canonical post **cannot** be specific, this results in far too few questions being related to the canonical post and it becomes less of a reference for the community
- The canonical post should be vague and then carry on to list and describe thoroughly (but not too much) the "sub-topics" of the general question
- A canonical post should also include links to previous questions in the past that may help any new questions that have something related to the canonical post, and to ensure it covers a larger area of questions

> 3. Since there are also some good, instructive answers in Astronomy SE that nicely complement those here, would it be okay to include links to them as well?

I agree, anything that nicely complements anything else can be included, e.g. a question from a programming site used as a resource for an astronomy site for calculating the orbits of a satellite.

> 4. OR should we NOT reference this body of work, and let new folks write new answers to new questions, then close them as duplicates later?

We should reference the canonical post, but if we create the post and don't reference it, then it's of little use :D